# Browse to a file directory and display its files in a listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, web-applications

Would anyone offer tips, links, code snippets on how to browse to a file folder from within an ASP.NET 3.5 web application and list the folder contents within a ListView?

Regards,
Rey R. [neophyte web application developer]

Comment: are you trying to browse the client machines file structure, or the servers?

Comment: By the way, I'm not looking for a complete solution, just a couple of puzzle pieces that I could help me (e.g. How do I populate a listview programmatically...every example I've found uses a sqldatasource control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean at the client? In which case, using regular methods you are limited to the `<input type="file"/>` and whatever that does in your user's browser.

Beyond that, you need additional tools; for example, flash or Silverlight - which would allow access, but even that may be sand-boxed for security.

You certainly can't list the user's files from the server.

Comment: Yes, that's right; the user will have to be able to list files on a local desktop folder. Security is not an issue (for now).

Silverlight or Flash? Don't know Flash but have started to teach myself Silverlight. I will look into that avenue. 

Regards,
Rey

Answer (score 0):

Upload Multiple Files in ASP.NET using jQuery

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=317